# Angular otherwise doesn't work in case of <a href>

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following  in one of my templates (under a folder name "partials")

```
<a href="index.html">&laquo; Back to search</a>
```

in one  of my js I define the routing in the following way:

```
var app=angular.module("app",['ngRoute', 'playerControllers']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
      when('/list',{
    templateUrl:'partials/list.html',
    controller: 'ListController'
  }).
      when('/details/:itemId',{
        templateUrl:'partials/details.html',
        controller: 'DetailsController'
      }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}]);
```

For some reason when I click on the back link it doesn't get to
http://localhost:63342/mcaabiTLV/app/index.html#/list as he should. Instead it gets to 
http://localhost:63342/mcaabiTLV/app/index.html#

Comment: Do you mean the back button of the browser?

Comment: K. Gkinis- no the back link I wrote- <a href="index.html">&laquo; Back to search</a>

Comment: write after `redirectTo: '/list'` `,resolve: {  alert("otherwise");    }` and see if it gets called

Comment: @K. Gkinis- inside the otherwise?

Comment: yes, I'm proposing this to check if it does get called (it doesn't I think)

Comment: @K. Gkinis- the syntax is not right. I get error when I add it

Answer (score 0):

You should write instead:

```
<a href="#/list">&laquo; Back to search</a>
```